# How can I prevent GDI+ from re-drawing everything on paint?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I want to change the colour of certain parts of a control which is using GDI+ to draw itself, like when certain objects are hovered/clicked, for example.

How can I re-draw only the necessary parts? It seems bad to re-draw thousands of pixels when I only need to make a change to a few of them.

To be specific, I have drawn anywhere from 1 to 128 rectangles, and I will need to re-draw anywhere from 1 to 128 rectangles in various events. I don't want to re-draw 128 rectangles in order to make a change to only 1-127.

I have read that it is a *bad* idea to use drawing code in places which are not the on paint event. But, is it possible to do this when relying on the paint event?

Comment: Easy way is to make each "rectangle" a control with it's own paint routine. Then have another container type control that "knows" how the rectangle controls it owns.

Comment: This is already heavily optimized in Windows through the PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle property.  Anything you draw outside of that rectangle completes very quickly without burning cycles.  Just use Invalidate(Rectangle) to set it.

Comment: Invalidate() with a Rectangle is perfect, thanks!~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of the [`Control.Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx) methods to specify the region you want to redraw.
Then in the Paint event hander you can check the invalidated region with the [`e.ClipRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.cliprectangle.aspx) property.